# My Computer (This PC) won't open from Desktop or Start or Search

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

I've recently installed Windows 8.1 x64 in my laptop Dell Inspiron 3542. The 'This PC' (My Computer) icon was working fine initially, i.e., I could access all my drives. But then there were some installation messages at Windows startup which were asking me to install aim.exe and another thing. I removed them permanently from my system, and rebooted it, after which I couldn't access my drives. Nothing happens when I click on the icon, either from Desktop or Start or Search. But, if I hold down the Shift key and right click on the icon, an 'Open in new process' option opens the window correctly and I can access my drives. Also, it works correctly when I boot into safe mode. How do I fix this?

Comment: It has been solved after running a Malwarebytes Anti-Malware scan.

Comment: Vote to close as it can no longer be reproduced

Comment: How do I do that? I'm accessing Stack Exchange from an Android smartphone, just FYI.

Comment: My comment was aimed at peopled who can vote to close. You can just delete your question if you like ;)